# use woocommerce get_date_on_sale_to() in javascript countdown timer

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, timer

I have a problem with use woocommerce get_date_on_sale_to() in javascript countdown timer. My code is:

```
<script>
var countDownDate = new Date(<?php echo $product->get_date_on_sale_to(); ?>).getTime();
var x = setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

i think this line is invalid :

```
var countDownDate = new Date(<?php echo $product->get_date_on_sale_to(); ?>).getTime();
```

output of this code `<?php echo $product->get_date_on_sale_to(); ?>` is `"2018-01-25T00:00:00-01:00"`
but my coutdown timer display : `NaN d NaN h NaN m NaN s`
how to fix it??????

Answer (score 0):

You first need to exctract `Date` from string, like:

```
//You'll get date in milliseconds since 1970/01/01, so don't need to use getTime()
var countDownDate = Date.parse(<?php echo $product->get_date_on_sale_to(); ?>);
```

More about `Date.parse` can find  [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

Also, here `var distance = countDownDate - now;` you getting negative number, try so:

```
var distance = now - countDownDate;
```

Comment: NaN NaN NaN NaN

Comment: try to echo `$product->get_date_on_sale_to();` without using js functions. what is the value of it?